# Crash Dumps Not Being Created On Windows Server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, crash-dumps

I'm trying to create crash dump files for a crashing IIS/.NET process on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've written the following PowerShell script as part of code deployment which works correctly for local development, but with the same Registry keys set on the application server, dump files are not created. I've checked the permissions for `SYSTEM` on the registry and the collection folder and they seem to be correct, so I'm not quite sure why the dump files aren't being generated.

Running a test application on the server that does nothing but crash via a stack overflow just generates an application pop-up, but no dump files.

I tried all of the possible solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469083/1064169), and none of them have resolved the problem.

[image: A new guard page for the stack cannot be created]

```bsh
$dumpFolder = "C:\crash-dumps"

if (!(Test-Path $dumpFolder)) {
    mkdir $dumpFolder | Out-Null
}

$dumpKey = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps"

if (!(Test-Path $dumpKey)) {
    New-Item -Path $dumpKey | Out-Null
}

$dumpKey = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\dotnet.exe"
New-Item -Path $dumpKey -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpFolder -Value $dumpFolder -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpCount -Value 3 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpType -Value 2 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

$dumpKey = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\w3wp.exe"

New-Item -Path $dumpKey -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpFolder -Value $dumpFolder -PropertyType String -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpCount -Value 3 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $dumpKey -Name DumpType -Value 2 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
```

Comment: The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) states that `DumpFolder` should be a 'REG_EXPAND_SZ' type, which is passed as 'ExpandString' when using `New-ItemProperty`.  You pass it as 'String'.  Not sure if it will help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: But on my laptop it is not `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, and it still works. Also, the path is hard-coded and doesn't contain any environment variables that need expanding. It also tried changing the type, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, thought it was a long shot.

Comment: Does the process have sufficient privileges to write to that folder?

Comment: I believe so, as the System account had write access. Dumps don't get created with the Windows default if I don't use a custom folder either though.

Comment: Try setting DontShowUI to 1, we had troubles capturing dumps without it: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Servers/IIS/tools/SetupTestEnvironment.ps1#L80

Comment: @PavelKrymets Thanks, I'll give that a try. I also notice that you're restarting WER too.

Comment: I've tried this on a vanilla AWS EC2 instance with Server 2012 R2, and the default WER pops up, which generates the dump when interacted with. Disabling the UI just generates the dump with no pop-up. I wonder whether in my case there's something else installed overriding the default WER handler/UI, which is stopping WER from getting a chance to intercept the crash in the first place.

Comment: So `DontShowUI` doesn't fix that UI pop-up, so it must be being generated by something other than WER. It's likely once I solve whatever that is, I'll probably need it anyway.

Comment: This seems to be some strange artifact of _something_ custom on our Windows 2012 R2 AWS AMIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows does not produce full crash dumps even though registry is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457570/windows-does-not-produce-full-crash-dumps-even-though-registry-is-set-correctly)

Comment: @ThomasWeller None of the suggestions in the other question resolved the issue before this question was posted. Have edited to state that explicitly.

Comment: @MartinCostello: I have added two options since then. Did you check "User settings instead of machine settings"?

Comment: Yes, I checked that too.

Comment: @MartinCostello , were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @AntonK I'm afraid not. We've upgraded from 2012 R2 now, and don't need to solve it anymore either.